# Blending linear gradient with background

Tags: css

I'm looking to allow a single line of elements overflow their container and scroll horizontally, but instead of a hard cut at the edge of the outer element, a fade out effect is needed.

Pseudo elements with linear gradients:

```
 <div class="bg">
  <span class="white">Lorem ipsum dolor....</span>
 </div>

.bg {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 23px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.white {
  color: #4a525a;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 100px;
  width: 700px;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 500px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scroll: touch;
}
.bg::before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white 30%, transparent);
}
.bg::after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, white 30%, transparent);
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/Megagator/pen/jPLzPe?editors=110

This works as expected in Chrome and Firefox, however Safari blends the gradients and background incorrectly. Is there a more compatible way to accomplish this effect with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Safari is strictly following the standard for the transparent shorthand:

> transparent
>   Fully transparent. This keyword can be considered a shorthand for
>   transparent black, rgba(0,0,0,0), which is its computed value.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparent

Explicitly stating white transparent resolves this:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white 30%, rgba(255,255,255,0));
```

Comment: Safari may actually be unaware of [this addition to a different spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#color-stop-syntax), which is what the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox are following.

Comment: @BoltClock Ahh, this is what I assumed Chrome and FF were doing, didn't know about that special case spec for gradients. Makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

Use `rgb(255,255,255,0)` instead of `transparent`.

```
.bg::after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #fff 30%, rgba(255,255,255,0));
}
```